# Extract manufacture data of BLE in android lollipop

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In lollipop version ,the scan result method returns all the details of BLE such as address ,name scan record,rssi etc.I have broadcasted some data in manufacture data field.I tried using `getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData()` in order to extract the manufacture data alone and strore in a string ,but they have used a sparse array to store the data.is there any way to extract the data alone from that array .

so here is the LOGCAT data:

> 12-05 17:31:39.101: I/ScanningMode(31818): Found advertisement with
>   device name: DA14580-01, device bond state: 12, device address:
>   80:EA:CA:00:00:01, device type: 2, device Bluetooth class: 1f00, RSSI:
>   -86, scan record: ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={514=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]},
>   mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648,
>   mDeviceName=DA14580-01],Service data:{},tx level:-2147483648

When i tried to use

```
System.out.println("scan value :"+result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData());
```

I got like this in logcat
:

> 12-05 17:31:39.102: I/System.out(31818): scan value :{514=[B@61ce5dc}

can anybody correct me how to get the data alone (here i should get only 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)

Also i have broadcasted 14 packets from BLE device ,but the log cat show only 12 data packets .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i havent used .getManufacturerSpecificData(). I have picked data out of the scanRecord manually, obviously it should be done dynamically but in my case i knew that data would be in the same place.

i converted the scanRecord from bytes to Hex, and stored it as a string, i then used substring to pick out the required data.

```
 String advertData = DataManipulation.bytesToHex(scanRecord);
 if (advertData.contains(iBeaconIdentity)){
    String majorV = adData.substring(50, 54);
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.